# Find orthogonal projection of $(-1,1,2,2)^T$ on $Span(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{v_1}=\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1},\vec{v_2}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\2\\2}$.

I've tried using this formula:

$\vec{p}=\frac{\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,\vec{v_1}\rangle}{||\vec{v_1}||^2}+\frac{\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,\vec{v_2}\rangle}{||\vec{v_2}||^2}$

which seems to give me the wrong result since $(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$ is not an orthogonal set. How can I find the orthogonal projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to $\{v_1,v_2\}$, thereby getting an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. Then the answer to your question will be $\bigl\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,e_1\bigr\rangle e_1+\bigl\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,e_2\bigr\rangle e_2$. In your case, you will get$$e_1=\frac12(1,1,1,1)\text{ and }e_2=\frac12(-1,-1,1,1).$$

Comment: Are you saying I should use Gram-Schmidt to get an orthogonal basis to $(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$?

Comment: No, since I don't know that that means. What I suggested was that you get an orthonormal basis of the space spanned by your vectors.

Comment: OK, after I've used Gram-Schmidt, should I then use the formula I wrote for $\vec{p}$ with the $\vec{e_1}$ and $\vec{e_2}$?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you will not have to divide by the squares of the norms, since the vectors will have norm $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization like José Carlos Santos suggested in another answer, you can also write $$\vec{p} = \alpha_1 \vec v_1 + \alpha_2\vec v_2$$ and solve the conditions $$\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T -\vec{p}, \vec v_1\rangle=\langle(-1,1,2,2)^T -\vec{p},\vec v_2\rangle=0$$ for coefficients $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. These conditions take form of a system of linear equations:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l} \alpha_1 \langle\vec v_1, \vec v_1\rangle + \alpha_2 \langle\vec v_2, \vec v_1\rangle = \langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,\vec v_1\rangle \\ \alpha_1 \langle\vec v_1, \vec v_2\rangle + \alpha_2 \langle\vec v_2, \vec v_2\rangle = \langle(-1,1,2,2)^T,\vec v_2\rangle \end{array}\right.$$
That is 
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l} 4\alpha_1 + 4\alpha_2  = 4 \\ 4\alpha_1  + 8\alpha_2  = 8 \end{array}\right. $$

Comment: One might even spot that $(-1,1,2,2)^T-\vec v_2$ is orthogonal to both $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ without having to expand and solve the equations.

Comment: Yeah, but guessing and checking is sometimes not considered a proper solution of a problem.

Comment: I’m all for avoiding unnecessary work when one understands the underlying principles. Spotting relations among the entities one is working with is IMO an important part of mathematical thinking.